# Convert SVG string to URL Blob and insert to Canvas?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, svg, canvas

I have a problem I can't seem to be able to solve...
When I put an 'Image()' object (of SVG type) with a proper file path inside the 'context.drawImage(img, 0 ,0)' function, everything seems to work correctly.

However, I need to keep modifying parts of the SVG , such as scaling without stretching the graphics, and this doesn't seem possible with regular canvas functions, or at least insufficient enough for my needs.

I was able to do this before when I put the SVG element in the DOM, without canvas, and then I manipulated its attributes using getElementByID() and setAttribute(), which worked fine. I couldn't however get it into a Canvas...

So my idea was to treat the SVG data as a string inside the TS/JS file, and then convert it into an image file and finally getting it on the Canvas.
Problem is it does not render anything, but if you copy the 'blob' link to the browser it displays correctly.

Here is the StackBlitz project to demonstrate the problem:

[**StackBlitz SVG to Canvas project**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/canvas-example-angular-jjapl4?devtoolsheight=33&file=app/app.component.ts)

**Some of the code:**

```
let svg = `<svg id="svg-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
       ...
     </svg>`;

const blob = new Blob([svg], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const image = document.createElement("img");
image.addEventListener("load", () => URL.revokeObjectURL(url), {
  once: true
});

image.src = url;

console.log(image.src);
console.log(url); // Check the URL in the browser, including blob:,
// it should display fine.

ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100); // I don't get why it doesn't
// ctx.restore();
```

Comment: drawImage needs to go in the eventListener callback.